# Move ubuntu 16.10 from small to large HDD

Tags: partitioning

The Computer is an AMD 64 x 2 CPU, Graphics is Gallium 0.4 NVAB, OS 64 bit, Disk 15.4 GB, ubuntu 16.10
Wish to move entire contents of OS to a 320 GB, *unpartitioned* clean wiped HDD using DBAN. Downloaded GParted and YUMI, but unable to launch either one.
Present OS has restricted extra package installed and working. When installing ubuntu 16.10 from a Live DVD to the new disk. it does *not* install the restricted extras package, regardless of my checking said box during the install. The restricted extras package can be accessed on the present small HDD ubuntu OS. Is there a terminal procedure where I could copy the restricted package to a flash drive, and then copy same to the new larger HDD after installing the OS from live DVD?

Comment: 16.10 is past End Of Life, and is no longer supported here. Consider installing a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: The default 'release-upgrade' path from 16.10 was to 17.04, then 17.10 then 18.04.  16.10 & 17.04 are both now EOL, so I'd really consider taking note of your packages/programs, then do a clean install with a supported version of Ubuntu.  Standard releases are only supported for 9 months, so stick to a LTS (long-term-support) version if you don't want to release-upgrade every 9 months.

Comment: because 16.10 is EOL the repositories have moved. I recommend installing 16.04, or waiting 2 months for 18.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Without the restricted extras package, ubuntu is of very little use for my purposes.  Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: You can also create backup of your important data and then use it in your new installation.

Comment: Issue solved.  I have chosen to reload ubuntu 16.04, and continue until 18.04 becomes available. Many thanks to those who responded to my question.